# Gnome3 shows old icons for Network Manager

Tags: network-manager, gnome

I just upgraded to gnome3 ppa in ubuntu 11.04. Every thing is running smoothly after the upgrade, except the network manager icon, which is the old gnome's icons and the ubuntu network manager. Its driving me insane. I want the latest gnome network manager icons and the interface. Is there any way to fix that?

here are the screenshots

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ppa:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu natty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu natty main
```

Next: update and ugrade system in terminal.
Then: `sudo apt-get install network-manager`
Next: System reset.

P.S I installed Gnome3 for 11.04 and I lost 3 days of my life, I think it's crap (for now), it is very buggy, it should be called "Gnome3 pre-alpha for Natty". Now, I appreciate UNITY is much better. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are running the GNOME Shell, you will see the old icon, and this is a known problem that will probably be fixed by GNOME 3.2.

Comment: no, what i mean is that the default network manager icon for gnome shell is this :http://k3rnel.net/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/networkmanager-232x300.png. Which I am not getting.

Comment: I'm running gnome shell in ubuntu

Comment: @Ubuntuser, sorry. It is likely that it doesn't work correctly in Ubuntu as yet, so it is probably just a matter of time.

Answer (score 0):

Well... about the icon you just need to change the Icon theme of your system (try with gnome-tweak-tool). With the way the network menu shows up I have the same problem :S (I'm running Gnome-Shell 3.0.2)  I've tried by changing the theme but no matter what theme I use still it keeps displaying it like in gnome 2!

If someone knows how to fix that please help! :D

Regards!